# Configuring ReplyingKafkaTemplate for getting the responses from multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a requirement where I must use the synchronous request-reply pattern with Kafka, hence I am using **ReplyingKafkaTemplate** for the same.

As a part of implementation, there is a producer which is pushing a request message on one topic(**input-message-topic1**) but in return I am expecting responses from two topics(**output-message-topic1** and **output-message-topic2**) which I have to aggregate and process further.

Question : Is it possible to implement the above scenario with **ReplyingKafkaTemplate** / **AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate** or any other implementation which uses synchronous request-reply pattern with Kafka ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate` will do this; just configure its listener container to consume from both topics; the replies must contain the correlation id header (used to aggregate).

Comment: Thank You Gary for your response. I tried the suggestion and it is working as expected.

Comment: I am not sure if I have to post new Question , but what are changes I have to implement to make the above solution compatible with multiple consumer instances as currently at a time only one consumer host is getting the response.

Comment: The consumers must be in different groups (`group.id`); if they are all in the same group, only one will get the request. If you mean multiple template instances making requests to multiple server instances, see [the documentation(https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#replying-template). If you are still having problems, ask a new question with your code/config and more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are publishing from a producer and subscribing to an individual listener based on any criteria, and that single listener writes back to an individual response topic, you can simply configure your producer to listen back from an array list of topics

String[] requestReplyTopics = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda"};

```
@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Model> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, Model> cf) {
  ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(requestReplyTopic);
  return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
}
```