# Configuring AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate for getting the responses from multiple topics and multiple consumer instances

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

This is in continuation of another Question which I posted.
Below is the link for previous questions : [Aggregation of messages from multiple topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312945/configuring-replyingkafkatemplate-for-getting-the-responses-from-multiple-topics)

I have a requirement for which I have tried to create a diagram.[image: Desired Implementation]

**My requirement is to make sure that node1 should receive the responses R1M1 & R1M2 and node2 should receive the R2M1 & R2M2.**

Things which are implemented:

- Setting the **KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID** in the Producer Record from both the nodes.
- KafkaMessageListenerContainer bean created with the two response topics in Container Properties.
  **ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(output-message-topic1, output-message-topic2);**
- **aggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate.setSharedReplyTopic(true);**
- **consumerFactory is configured with single groupId.**

  ```
   consumerConfigProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "xxxx.yyyyy.zzzz");
  ```

**Note** :

- I am able to achieve the aggregations of multiple response message with one node.
- Creating separate topic for each consumer(node) is not possible because of infra limitation.

I need assistance on changes which needs to be implemented to get the associated aggregated response for a request.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#replying-template).

You MUST configure each instance to use a discrete reply topic partition and the server must route the reply to the requested partition; or you must use a different `group.id` for each instance so that replies are sent to both (and discarded by the instance that did not emit the request).

> When you configure with a single reply `TopicPartitionOffset`, you can use the same reply topic for multiple templates, as long as each instance listens on a different partition. When configuring with a single reply topic, each instance must use a different `group.id`. In this case, all instances receive each reply, but only the instance that sent the request finds the correlation ID. This may be useful for auto-scaling, but with the overhead of additional network traffic and the small cost of discarding each unwanted reply. When you use this setting, we recommend that you set the template’s `sharedReplyTopic` to true, which reduces the logging level of unexpected replies to DEBUG instead of the default ERROR.

> If you have multiple client instances and you do not configure them as discussed in the preceding paragraph, each instance needs a dedicated reply topic. An alternative is to set the `KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION` and use a dedicated partition for each instance. The Header contains a four-byte int (big-endian). The server must use this header to route the reply to the correct partition (`@KafkaListener` does this). In this case, though, the reply container must not use Kafka’s group management feature and must be configured to listen on a fixed partition (by using a `TopicPartitionOffset` in its `ContainerProperties` constructor).

Comment: Russel : I think I have a need of creating 2 reply TopicPartitionOffset. Below is the way I have configured my **KafkaMessageListenerContainer** bean . `TopicPartitionOffset topic1offset =  new TopicPartitionOffset(response-topic-1,0);
        TopicPartitionOffset topic2offset =  new TopicPartitionOffset(response-topic-2,0);
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topic1offset,topic2offset);` and my implementation does have multiple client instances .Does it mean that I will have to use the 2nd approach of using KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION ?

Comment: With 2 topics, each instance should only listen on one topic. One on topic-1, the other on topic-2. That way, the template can automatically set the reply headers and you don’t need to worry about them. You can also use two partitions in a single topic that way.